# Re-render Tweet button via JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter

I used to use [this snippet](http://forrst.com/posts/Render_Tweet_Button_in_AJAX_Loaded_Content-7cx) to re-render a Tweet button.

```
var tweetButton = new twttr.TweetButton(twitterScript);
twttr.render();
```

But it looks like widgets.js (http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) has been modified so twttr.TweetButton is no longer a constructor.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Same problem here! It just stopped working within the last 24 hours!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the `twttr.TweetButton` constructor was never supported, and now no longer works after the last API update:

- http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/bcda486acdf4ab42/6a557050f850ccf2?lnk=gst&q=+twttr.TweetButton#6a557050f850ccf2

The supported method is to create an `iframe`-based Tweet button dynamically:

- http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button#using-an-iframe

Although note [@Runningskull’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10789374/20578) for updated information.

Answer (score 45):

I found the answer on the [web](http://www.ovaistariq.net/447/how-to-dynamically-create-twitters-tweet-button-and-facebooks-like-button/). The idea is to re-request the Twitter javascript file. As it is cached, there is no download overhead.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', dataType: 'script', cache:true});
```

Comment: Works fine. First I was worried that I would get multiple scripts with conflicts and overhead but i seems jQuery handles that!

Comment: what if a have a lot of twitter buttons on my page? how can i re-render only one (for example the one inside a div with and id)

Comment: @MartinSchaer I don't think you can with this method. You'll need to rely on iframe-based method or something else instead.

Answer (score 23):

For anyone stumbling onto this, there's a new, easier way to do it (as of 5/28/12 if not before). A quick glance didn't find it in the documentation, but you can do `twttr.widgets.load()`. That'll [re]load all the widgets on the page.

EDIT: It is documented, after all. Check out [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents)'s "Optimization" section (which you can't link to directly)

Comment: This is definitively the current answer.  Adding a twttr.widgets.load() wil refresh all twitter content for div's created after twitter script loads. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

you just need to call `twttr.widgets.load()` after your ajax call. no need to reload a script that is already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have jQuery included in your document's head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then create a link that has the same URL as the eventual tweet button, along with an empty div where your button will be rendered:

```
<a href="http://www.my-site-to-tweet-about.com" id="tlink"></a>
<div id="tbutton"></div>
```

At the bottom of your page, right above the /body tag, include the javascript from Twitter and the function that will render the button, as well as the listener that will activate the function when the desired event takes place:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//async script, twitter button fashiolista.com style
    (function() {
    var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    var c = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.defer = "defer";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    c.parentNode.insertBefore(s, c);
    })();

function renderTweetButton(tbutton,tlink){
    var href = $("#"+tlink).attr('href'),
        $target = $("#"+tbutton),
        qstring = $.param({ url: href, count: "vertical" }),
        toinsert = '<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?'+qstring+'" style="width:57px; height:70px;"></iframe>';
    $target.html(toinsert);
}

$("#hoverlink").mouseenter(function() {
    renderTweetButton("tbutton","tlink");
});
</script>
```

Lastly, add a link to your page somewhere that will activate the function above based on some event:

```
<a href="#" id="hoverlink">Hover here to render a tweet button to div#tbutton.</a>
```

That's it.

If you want the entire test HTML page to see how I've got it working, see here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery Twitter Button Render Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<a href="http://www.my-site-to-tweet-about.com" id="tlink"></a>
<div id="tbutton"></div>

<a href="#" id="hoverlink">Hover here to render a tweet button to div#tbutton.</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
//async script, twitter button fashiolista.com style
    (function() {
    var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    var c = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.defer = "defer";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    c.parentNode.insertBefore(s, c);
    })();

function renderTweetButton(tbutton,tlink){
    var href = $("#"+tlink).attr('href'),
        $target = $("#"+tbutton),
        qstring = $.param({ url: href, count: "vertical" }),
        toinsert = '<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?'+qstring+'" style="width:57px; height:70px;"></iframe>';
    $target.html(toinsert);
}

$("#hoverlink").mouseenter(function() {
    renderTweetButton("tbutton","tlink");
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, this works in JQuery:

```
$.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the @Anywhere library.  Sample js code:

```
twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
        T("#tweetbox").tweetBox({
        counter: false,
        defaultContent: "Default text in a Tweet box...",
        label: "Share this page on Twitter"
});
```

Comment: I've looked into @Anywhere, but I need to use the Tweet button and not the Tweet box.