# Embedding a Twitter share button (with JS and everything) into a Mustache template

Tags: javascript, dom, twitter, mustache

How can I embed a Twitter (with JS and everything) share button into a Mustache template?

The problem which I have is that my AJAX app does not reload the page, but simply switches views based on Mustache templates. I noticed that functionality provided by widjets.js simply does not get turned on, because the JS files gets loaded only once per application lifetime, and searches for tags decorated with a "twitter" tag on DOM_READY. This however, completely excludes the cases when HTML gets rendered from a template later on.

I know that I can use a raw hyperlink to twitter and customize it to o look like a button, but that is just too primitive.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that worked for me using a template inside my HTML file:

**social.js:**

```
$(function() {
  var socialFeeds = {
    twitter: {
      account: "your-twitter-account",
      script: function() {
        // twitter code goes here, minus the script tags
        !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");

        // in my case, I had to re-render the twitter button, see here:
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/6536108/805003
        $.ajax({ url: 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', dataType: 'script', cache:true});
      }
    }
  }

  $.Mustache.addFromDom('social-template');
  $('#social').mustache('social-template', socialFeeds);
}
```

**index.html:**

```
    <script id="social-template" type="text/html">
      <div id='social'>
          <p>Twitter button:</p>

          <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="{{twitter.account}}">Tweet</a>
          {{ twitter.script }}
      </div>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call the init functions not on `document ready` but from the views where you want the twitter button to appear.