# jQuery - set user defined var

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery sharrre plugin in my site. but there is a problem.
I want to change a default variable of plugin, and how to do it outside the plugin code .

There is a default variable in plugin code

```
urlCurl: 'sharrre.php',  //PHP script for google plus...
```

is it possible to set this var outside the plugin  like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
  defaults = {
    urlCurl: '<?php echo get_template_directory() . '/inc/sharrre.php' ?>'
    }
});
```

**This is sharrre plugin code**

```
/*
 *  Sharrre.com - Make your sharing widget!
 *  Version: beta 1.3.3 
 *  Author: Julien Hany
 *  License: MIT http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License or GPLv2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License
 */

;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

  /* Defaults
  ================================================== */
  var pluginName = 'sharrre',
  defaults = {
    className: 'sharrre',
    share: {
      googlePlus: false,
      facebook: false,
      twitter: false,
      digg: false,
      delicious: false,
      stumbleupon: false,
      linkedin: false,
      pinterest: false
    },
    shareTotal: 0,
    template: '',
    title: '',
    url: document.location.href,
    text: document.title,
    urlCurl: 'sharrre.php',  //PHP script for google plus...
    count: {}, //counter by social network
    total: 0,  //total of sharing
    shorterTotal: true, //show total by k or M when number is to big
    enableHover: true, //disable if you want to personalize hover event with callback
    enableCounter: true, //disable if you just want use buttons
    enableTracking: false, //tracking with google analitycs
    hover: function(){}, //personalize hover event with this callback function
    hide: function(){}, //personalize hide event with this callback function
    click: function(){}, //personalize click event with this callback function
    render: function(){}, //personalize render event with this callback function
    buttons: {  //settings for buttons
      googlePlus : {  //http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/
        url: '',  //if you need to personnalize button url
        urlCount: false,  //if you want to use personnalize button url on global counter
        size: 'medium',
        lang: 'en-US',
        annotation: ''
      },
      facebook: { //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
        url: '',  //if you need to personalize url button
        urlCount: false,  //if you want to use personnalize button url on global counter
        action: 'like',
        layout: 'button_count',
        width: '',
        send: 'false',
        faces: 'false',
        colorscheme: '',
        font: '',
        lang: 'en_US'
      },
      twitter: {  //http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton
        url: '',  //if you need to personalize url button
        urlCount: false,  //if you want to use personnalize button url on global counter
        count: 'horizontal',
        hashtags: '',
        via: '',
        related: '',
        lang: 'en'
      },
      digg: { //http://about.digg.com/downloads/button/smart
        url: '',  //if you need to personalize url button
        urlCount: false,  //if you want to use personnalize button url on global counter
        type: 'DiggCompact'
      },
      delicious: {
        url: '',  //if you need to personalize url button
        urlCount: false,  //if you want to use personnalize button url on global counter
        size: 'medium' //medium or tall
      },
      stumbleupon: {  //http://www.stumbleupon.com/badges/
        url: '',  //if you need to personalize url button
        urlCount: false,  //if you want to use personnalize button url on global counter
        layout: '1'
      },
      linkedin: {  //http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-button
        url: '',  //if you need to personalize url button
        urlCount: false,  //if you want to use personnalize button url on global counter
        counter: ''
      },
      pinterest: { //http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/
        url: '',  //if you need to personalize url button
        media: '',
        description: '',
        layout: 'horizontal'
      }
    }
  },
  /* Json URL to get count number
  ================================================== */
  urlJson = {
    googlePlus: "",
    //new FQL method by Sire
    facebook: "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27{url}%27&callback=?",
    //old method facebook: "http://graph.facebook.com/?id={url}&callback=?",
    //facebook : "http://api.ak.facebook.com/restserver.php?v=1.0&method=links.getStats&urls={url}&format=json"
    twitter: "http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url={url}&callback=?",
    digg: "http://services.digg.com/2.0/story.getInfo?links={url}&type=javascript&callback=?",
    delicious: 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url={url}&callback=?',
    //stumbleupon: "http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url={url}&format=jsonp&callback=?",
    stumbleupon: "",
    linkedin: "http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?format=jsonp&url={url}&callback=?",
    pinterest: ""
  },
  /* Load share buttons asynchronously
  ================================================== */
  loadButton = {
    googlePlus : function(self){
      var sett = self.options.buttons.googlePlus;
      //$(self.element).find('.buttons').append('<div class="button googleplus"><g:plusone size="'+self.options.buttons.googlePlus.size+'" href="'+self.options.url+'"></g:plusone></div>');
      $(self.element).find('.buttons').append('<div class="button googleplus"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="'+sett.size+'" data-href="'+(sett.url !== '' ? sett.url : self.options.url)+'" data-annotation="'+sett.annotation+'"></div></div>');
      window.___gcfg = {
        lang: self.options.buttons.googlePlus.lang
      };
      var loading = 0;
      if(typeof gapi === 'undefined' && loading == 0){
        loading = 1;
        (function() {
          var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
          po.src = '//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
      }
      else{
        gapi.plusone.go();
      }
    },
    facebook : function(self){
      var sett = self.options.buttons.facebook;
      $(self.element).find('.buttons').append('<div class="button facebook"><div id="fb-root"></div><div class="fb-like" data-href="'+(sett.url !== '' ? sett.url : self.options.url)+'" data-send="'+sett.send+'" data-layout="'+sett.layout+'" data-width="'+sett.width+'" data-show-faces="'+sett.faces+'" data-action="'+sett.action+'" data-colorscheme="'+sett.colorscheme+'" data-font="'+sett.font+'" data-via="'+sett.via+'"></div></div>');
      var loading = 0;
      if(typeof FB === 'undefined' && loading == 0){
        loading = 1;
        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/'+sett.lang+'/all.js#xfbml=1';
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      }
      else{
        FB.XFBML.parse();
      }
    },
    twitter : function(self){
      var sett = self.options.buttons.twitter;
      $(self.element).find('.buttons').append('<div class="button twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="'+(sett.url !== '' ? sett.url : self.options.url)+'" data-count="'+sett.count+'" data-text="'+self.options.text+'" data-via="'+sett.via+'" data-hashtags="'+sett.hashtags+'" data-related="'+sett.related+'" data-lang="'+sett.lang+'">Tweet</a></div>');
      var loading = 0;
      if(typeof twttr === 'undefined' && loading == 0){
        loading = 1;
        (function() {
          var twitterScriptTag = document.createElement('script');
          twitterScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
          twitterScriptTag.async = true;
          twitterScriptTag.src = '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(twitterScriptTag, s);
        })();
      }
      else{
        $.ajax({ url: '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', dataType: 'script', cache:true}); //http://stackoverflow.com/q/6536108
      }
    },
    digg : function(self){
      var sett = self.options.buttons.digg;
      $(self.element).find('.buttons').append('<div class="button digg"><a class="DiggThisButton '+sett.type+'" rel="nofollow external" href="http://digg.com/submit?url='+encodeURIComponent((sett.url !== '' ? sett.url : self.options.url))+'"></a></div>');
      var loading = 0;
      if(typeof __DBW === 'undefined' && loading == 0){
        loading = 1;
        (function() {
          var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT'), s1 = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0];
          s.type = 'text/javascript';
          s.async = true;
          s.src = '//widgets.digg.com/buttons.js';
          s1.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s1);
        })();
      }
    },
    delicious : function(self){
      if(self.options.buttons.delicious.size == 'tall'){//tall
        var css = 'width:50px;',
        cssCount = 'height:35px;width:50px;font-size:15px;line-height:35px;',
        cssShare = 'height:18px;line-height:18px;margin-top:3px;';
      }
      else{//medium
        var css = 'width:93px;',
        cssCount = 'float:right;padding:0 3px;height:20px;width:26px;line-height:20px;',
        cssShare = 'float:left;height:20px;line-height:20px;';
      }
      var count = self.shorterTotal(self.options.count.delicious);
      if(typeof count === "undefined"){
        count = 0;
      }
      $(self.element).find('.buttons').append(
      '<div class="button delicious"><div style="'+css+'font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;cursor:pointer;color:#666666;display:inline-block;float:none;height:20px;line-height:normal;margin:0;padding:0;text-indent:0;vertical-align:baseline;">'+
      '<div style="'+cssCount+'background-color:#fff;margin-bottom:5px;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:3px;">'+count+'</div>'+
      '<div style="'+cssShare+'display:block;padding:0;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:50px;background-color:#7EACEE;border:1px solid #40679C;border-radius:3px;color:#fff;">'+
      '<img src="http://www.delicious.com/static/img/delicious.small.gif" height="10" width="10" alt="Delicious" /> Add</div></div></div>');

      $(self.element).find('.delicious').on('click', function(){
        self.openPopup('delicious');
      });
    },
    stumbleupon : function(self){
      var sett = self.options.buttons.stumbleupon;
      $(self.element).find('.buttons').append('<div class="button stumbleupon"><su:badge layout="'+sett.layout+'" location="'+(sett.url !== '' ? sett.url : self.options.url)+'"></su:badge></div>');
      var loading = 0;
      if(typeof STMBLPN === 'undefined' && loading == 0){
        loading = 1;
        (function() {
          var li = document.createElement('script');li.type = 'text/javascript';li.async = true;
          li.src = '//platform.stumbleupon.com/1/widgets.js'; 
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(li, s);
        })();
        s = window.setTimeout(function(){
          if(typeof STMBLPN !== 'undefined'){
            STMBLPN.processWidgets();
            clearInterval(s);
          }
        },500);
      }
      else{
        STMBLPN.processWidgets();
      }
    },
    linkedin : function(self){
      var sett = self.options.buttons.linkedin;
      $(self.element).find('.buttons').append('<div class="button linkedin"><script type="in/share" data-url="'+(sett.url !== '' ? sett.url : self.options.url)+'" data-counter="'+sett.counter+'"></script></div>');
      var loading = 0;
      if(typeof window.IN === 'undefined' && loading == 0){
        loading = 1;
        (function() {
          var li = document.createElement('script');li.type = 'text/javascript';li.async = true;
          li.src = '//platform.linkedin.com/in.js'; 
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(li, s);
        })();
      }
      else{
        window.IN.init();
      }
    },
    pinterest : function(self){
      var sett = self.options.buttons.pinterest;
      $(self.element).find('.buttons').append('<div class="button pinterest"><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+(sett.url !== '' ? sett.url : self.options.url)+'&media='+sett.media+'&description='+sett.description+'" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="'+sett.layout+'">Pin It</a></div>');

      (function() {
        var li = document.createElement('script');li.type = 'text/javascript';li.async = true;
        li.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js'; 
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(li, s);
      })();
    }
  },
  /* Tracking for Google Analytics
  ================================================== */
  tracking = {
    googlePlus: function(){},
    facebook: function(){
      //console.log('facebook');
      fb = window.setInterval(function(){
        if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
          FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(targetUrl) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like', targetUrl]);
          });
          FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(targetUrl) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'unlike', targetUrl]);
          });
          FB.Event.subscribe('message.send', function(targetUrl) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'send', targetUrl]);
          });
          //console.log('ok');
          clearInterval(fb);
        }
      },1000);
    },
    twitter: function(){
      //console.log('twitter');
      tw = window.setInterval(function(){
        if (typeof twttr !== 'undefined') {
          twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
            if (event) {
              _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'twitter', 'tweet']);
            }
          });
          //console.log('ok');
          clearInterval(tw);
        }
      },1000);
    },
    digg: function(){
      //if somenone find a solution, mail me !
      /*$(this.element).find('.digg').on('click', function(){
        _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'digg', 'add']);
      });*/
    },
    delicious: function(){},
    stumbleupon: function(){},
    linkedin: function(){
      function LinkedInShare() {
        _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'linkedin', 'share']);
      }
    },
    pinterest: function(){
      //if somenone find a solution, mail me !
    }
  },
  /* Popup for each social network
  ================================================== */
  popup = {
    googlePlus: function(opt){
      window.open("https://plus.google.com/share?hl="+opt.buttons.googlePlus.lang+"&url="+encodeURIComponent((opt.buttons.googlePlus.url !== '' ? opt.buttons.googlePlus.url : opt.url)), "", "toolbar=0, status=0, width=900, height=500");
    },
    facebook: function(opt){
      window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+encodeURIComponent((opt.buttons.facebook.url !== '' ? opt.buttons.facebook.url : opt.url))+"&t="+opt.text+"", "", "toolbar=0, status=0, width=900, height=500");
    },
    twitter: function(opt){
      window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+encodeURIComponent(opt.text)+"&url="+encodeURIComponent((opt.buttons.twitter.url !== '' ? opt.buttons.twitter.url : opt.url))+(opt.buttons.twitter.via !== '' ? '&via='+opt.buttons.twitter.via : ''), "", "toolbar=0, status=0, width=650, height=360");
    },
    digg: function(opt){
      window.open("http://digg.com/tools/diggthis/submit?url="+encodeURIComponent((opt.buttons.digg.url !== '' ? opt.buttons.digg.url : opt.url))+"&title="+opt.text+"&related=true&style=true", "", "toolbar=0, status=0, width=650, height=360");
    },
    delicious: function(opt){
      window.open('http://www.delicious.com/save?v=5&noui&jump=close&url='+encodeURIComponent((opt.buttons.delicious.url !== '' ? opt.buttons.delicious.url : opt.url))+'&title='+opt.text, 'delicious', 'toolbar=no,width=550,height=550');
    },
    stumbleupon: function(opt){
      window.open('http://www.stumbleupon.com/badge/?url='+encodeURIComponent((opt.buttons.delicious.url !== '' ? opt.buttons.delicious.url : opt.url)), 'stumbleupon', 'toolbar=no,width=550,height=550');
    },
    linkedin: function(opt){
      window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url='+encodeURIComponent((opt.buttons.delicious.url !== '' ? opt.buttons.delicious.url : opt.url))+'&token=&isFramed=true', 'linkedin', 'toolbar=no,width=550,height=550');
    },
    pinterest: function(opt){
      window.open('http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+encodeURIComponent((opt.buttons.pinterest.url !== '' ? opt.buttons.pinterest.url : opt.url))+'&media='+encodeURIComponent(opt.buttons.pinterest.media)+'&description='+opt.buttons.pinterest.description, 'pinterest', 'toolbar=no,width=700,height=300');
    }
  };

  /* Plugin constructor
  ================================================== */
  function Plugin( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;

    this.options = $.extend( true, {}, defaults, options);
    this.options.share = options.share; //simple solution to allow order of buttons

    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;

    this.init();
  };

  /* Initialization method
  ================================================== */
  Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
    var self = this;
    if(this.options.urlCurl !== ''){
      urlJson.googlePlus = this.options.urlCurl + '?url={url}&type=googlePlus'; // PHP script for GooglePlus...
      urlJson.stumbleupon = this.options.urlCurl + '?url={url}&type=stumbleupon'; // PHP script for Stumbleupon...
      urlJson.pinterest = this.options.urlCurl + '?url={url}&type=pinterest'; // PHP script for Pinterest...
    }
    $(this.element).addClass(this.options.className); //add class

    //HTML5 Custom data
    if(typeof $(this.element).data('title') !== 'undefined'){
      this.options.title = $(this.element).attr('data-title');
    }
    if(typeof $(this.element).data('url') !== 'undefined'){
      this.options.url = $(this.element).data('url');
    }
    if(typeof $(this.element).data('text') !== 'undefined'){
      this.options.text = $(this.element).data('text');
    }

    //how many social website have been selected
    $.each(this.options.share, function(name, val) {
      if(val === true){
        self.options.shareTotal ++;
      }
    });

    if(self.options.enableCounter === true){  //if for some reason you don't need counter
      //get count of social share that have been selected
      $.each(this.options.share, function(name, val) {
        if(val === true){
          //self.getSocialJson(name);
          try {
            self.getSocialJson(name);
          } catch(e){
          }
        }
      });
    }
    else if(self.options.template !== ''){  //for personalized button (with template)
      this.options.render(this, this.options);
    }
    else{ // if you want to use official button like example 3 or 5
      this.loadButtons();
    }

    //add hover event
    $(this.element).hover(function(){
      //load social button if enable and 1 time
      if($(this).find('.buttons').length === 0 && self.options.enableHover === true){
        self.loadButtons();
      }
      self.options.hover(self, self.options);
    }, function(){
      self.options.hide(self, self.options);
    });

    //click event
    $(this.element).click(function(){
      self.options.click(self, self.options);
      return false;
    });
  };

  /* loadButtons methode
  ================================================== */
  Plugin.prototype.loadButtons = function () {
    var self = this;
    $(this.element).append('<div class="buttons"></div>');
    $.each(self.options.share, function(name, val) {
      if(val == true){
        loadButton[name](self);
        if(self.options.enableTracking === true){ //add tracking
          tracking[name]();
        }
      }
    });
  };

  /* getSocialJson methode
  ================================================== */
  Plugin.prototype.getSocialJson = function (name) {
    var self = this,
    count = 0,
    url = urlJson[name].replace('{url}', encodeURIComponent(this.options.url));
    if(this.options.buttons[name].urlCount === true && this.options.buttons[name].url !== ''){
      url = urlJson[name].replace('{url}', this.options.buttons[name].url);
    }
    //console.log('name : ' + name + ' - url : '+url); //debug
    if(url != '' && self.options.urlCurl !== ''){  //urlCurl = '' if you don't want to used PHP script but used social button
      $.getJSON(url, function(json){
        if(typeof json.count !== "undefined"){  //GooglePlus, Stumbleupon, Twitter and Digg
          var temp = json.count + '';
          temp = temp.replace('\u00c2\u00a0', '');  //remove google plus special chars
          count += parseInt(temp, 10);
        }
        //get the FB total count (shares, likes and more)
        else if(json.data && json.data.length > 0 && typeof json.data[0].total_count !== "undefined"){ //Facebook total count
          count += parseInt(json.data[0].total_count, 10);
        }     
        else if(typeof json.shares !== "undefined"){  //Facebook
         count += parseInt(json.shares, 10);
        }
        else if(typeof json[0] !== "undefined"){  //Delicious
          count += parseInt(json[0].total_posts, 10);
        }
        else if(typeof json[0] !== "undefined"){  //Stumbleupon
        }
        self.options.count[name] = count;
        self.options.total += count;
        self.renderer();
        self.rendererPerso();
        //console.log(json); //debug
      })
      .error(function() { 
        self.options.count[name] = 0;
        self.rendererPerso();
       });
    }
    else{
      self.renderer();
      self.options.count[name] = 0;
      self.rendererPerso();
    }
  };

  /* launch render methode
  ================================================== */
  Plugin.prototype.rendererPerso = function () {
    //check if this is the last social website to launch render
    var shareCount = 0;
    for (e in this.options.count) { shareCount++; }
    if(shareCount === this.options.shareTotal){
      this.options.render(this, this.options);
    }
  };

  /* render methode
  ================================================== */
  Plugin.prototype.renderer = function () {
    var total = this.options.total,
    template = this.options.template;
    if(this.options.shorterTotal === true){  //format number like 1.2k or 5M
      total = this.shorterTotal(total);
    }

    if(template !== ''){  //if there is a template
      template = template.replace('{total}', total);
      $(this.element).html(template);
    }
    else{ //template by defaults
      $(this.element).html(
                            '<div class="box"><a class="count" href="#">' + total + '</a>' + 
                            (this.options.title !== '' ? '<a class="share" href="#">' + this.options.title + '</a>' : '') +
                            '</div>'
                          );
    }
  };

  /* format total numbers like 1.2k or 5M
  ================================================== */
  Plugin.prototype.shorterTotal = function (num) {
    if (num >= 1e6){
      num = (num / 1e6).toFixed(2) + "M"
    } else if (num >= 1e3){ 
      num = (num / 1e3).toFixed(1) + "k"
    }
    return num;
  };

  /* Methode for open popup
  ================================================== */
  Plugin.prototype.openPopup = function (site) {
    popup[site](this.options);  //open
    if(this.options.enableTracking === true){ //tracking!
      var tracking = {
        googlePlus: {site: 'Google', action: '+1'},
        facebook: {site: 'facebook', action: 'like'},
        twitter: {site: 'twitter', action: 'tweet'},
        digg: {site: 'digg', action: 'add'},
        delicious: {site: 'delicious', action: 'add'},
        stumbleupon: {site: 'stumbleupon', action: 'add'},
        linkedin: {site: 'linkedin', action: 'share'},
        pinterest: {site: 'pinterest', action: 'pin'}
      };
      _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', tracking[site].site, tracking[site].action]);
    }
  };

  /* Methode for add +1 to a counter
  ================================================== */
  Plugin.prototype.simulateClick = function () {
    var html = $(this.element).html();
    $(this.element).html(html.replace(this.options.total, this.options.total+1));
  };

  /* Methode for add +1 to a counter
  ================================================== */
  Plugin.prototype.update = function (url, text) {
    if(url !== ''){
      this.options.url = url;
    }
    if(text !== ''){
      this.options.text = text;
    }
  };

  /* A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor, preventing against multiple instantiations
  ================================================== */
  $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    var args = arguments;
    if (options === undefined || typeof options === 'object') {
      return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
          $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
      });
    } else if (typeof options === 'string' && options[0] !== '_' && options !== 'init') {
      return this.each(function () {
        var instance = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName);
        if (instance instanceof Plugin && typeof instance[options] === 'function') {
          instance[options].apply( instance, Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 ) );
        }
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the plugin documentation, but just based on looking at the syntax it seems like you want to use this:

```
$("selector").sharrre({urlCurl: '/path/inc/sharrre.php'});
```

I cannot advocate the mixing of PHP and JavaScript.  Get the correct path part by adding it to the DOM somehow, perhaps with `<base>`.

Comment: Oh i missed that. Ok i will use dom