# Embeding tweets inside angular ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I want to use [embeded tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets) inside an ng-view partial but for some reason it not working. if I put it outside of the partial (directly in the index.html) it works.
Does anyone has an idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: It seems that its working when embedding the partial view inside a script tag instead of putting it on a different file:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cnzxx/2/
Anyone knows why it doesn't work when the partial is on a different file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is order in which tweeter script and your main.html is loaded: when mail.html is loaded before widget.js, tweeter's script is not able to find your `backquote` element and render it nice way.

You can put `<script ...>` into main.html, but in this case keep in mind, that Angular's jqLite does not support `<script>` tags in partials, loaded via XHR. So you need to include real jQuery before angular.

Here is a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rQUThnZNAyJQGFIwflGk?p=preview

Comment: to understand the solution is just to include jQuery as a dependency?

Comment: I can't believe it is that simple, I have been messing around with this for days on multiple projects for what seems like a lifetime. I want to buy you a pizza (seriously)! thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. Actually, I hope, soon this answer would be not valid when we'll have good module loading system as part of ES6/ES7 that will unify all this kind of problems.

Answer (score 4):

It seams that we need to call again the twitter js - this isn't related to Angularjs in specific. Because Angular js partial view are not rendered immediately the problem happens. The solution is to call the js file again after the partial was loaded:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', dataType: 'script', cache:true});
}, 1000);
```

see: [Re-render Tweet button via JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206471/re-render-tweet-button-via-js/6536108#6536108)