# Tweet button doesn't appear when used in accordion with some browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I'm using the following code to display a twitter button to share a page from one website.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");});</script>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="/myUrl" data-text="message" data-hashtags="myhashtag">Tweet</a>
```

This code is working with no problem when used in a page, no matter the browser I'm using.

Now my problem begins when I want to put that button in an html accordion. When the  element is placed in something that is hidden at first the CSS behaves differently depending on the browser. On Chrome most of the time the tweet button is displayed when expanding the accordion. While on Internet Explorer and Firefox (I have not Edge to test it) the button is computed with size of 1px. If I use the developer tools to set correct sizes for the button in the CSS then it appears. The javascript does it's job : script is loaded and the iframe is here with all the necessary code, I have no problem with the load from the twitter website, my only problem is with the computed CSS that prevent the display of the button.

So I'm looking for help to display the button even if it is hidden at start.

**Edit : The below snippet is an attempt to demonstrate my problem.**

```css
.btn-o {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");});</script>
<p>
Tweet button not hidden at start
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="/myUrl" data-text="message" data-hashtags="myhashtag">Tweet</a>
</p>
<p>
Tweet button hidden at start

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Here is also a tweet button, if you see nothing you have my bug demonstrated (don't work with IE or Firefox most of the time)
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="/myUrl" data-text="message" data-hashtags="myhashtag">Tweet</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Someone solved a similar issue here, by checking the button width, and re-rendering it if necessary: https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-share-button-not-working-in-ie-and-ff-when-within-modal/101352

Comment: @misorude it seems to be exactly my problem thank you for the comment. I'll try it and will keep you updated.

Comment: @misorude thanks for your help I've posted my solution your post was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the solution I've managed to get it working and the explanation :

First explanation : twitter looks for the twitter-share-button to insert one iframe. Unfortunately if the content isn't visible then the size of the iframe will be 1.

Second manage the error : I had to add an event on my hidden content in order to handle the cases when the generated twitter iframe has a size of 1. So the idea is to add a new button and reload the twitter widget in order to replace the link by the iframe when the content is visible (we do that with twttr.widgets.load();). We also need to do that only once not each time that's why I've added one check on the iframe width before inserting content and reloading the widget.

```
$(".card").on('click',function(){
var width=0;
// calculates largest width for the iframe
$('#collapseOne').find('.card-body').find('iframe').each(function(){if (width < $(this).width()) {width=$(this).width()}});
// we do the following only if there is no larger iframe for the tweet button
// otherwise there is a risk to insert more than one button in the page
if(width < 2) {
$('#collapseOne').find('.card-body').append('<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="/myUrl" data-text="message" data-hashtags="myhashtag">Tweet</a>');
twttr.widgets.load();
}
});
```

Thanks to @misorude for suggesting the community post and to this post [Re-render Tweet button via JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206471/re-render-tweet-button-via-js/10789374#10789374) that helped me to reload the twitter widget.

Answer (score 0):

The class for the tweet button seems to be btn-o. Try adding a style for btn-o

```
.btn-o {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but it doesn't help : I've updated the snippet that I've created it still render nothing

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the problem with mozilla and after disabling add blocker the twitter button shows the first one outside of accordion:

[image]

after more investigating I found that you need to set some height and width to 100px or more and to disable one property overflow: hidden;

Here are sample screenshots and last thing you will need to create some mozilla/ firefox specific css class to handle this updates:

[image]

[image]

So you will need to use firefox specific css sample:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 //inside put class you want to override

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn-o {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");});</script>
<p>
Tweet button not hidden at start
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="/myUrl" data-text="message" data-hashtags="myhashtag">Tweet</a>
</p>
<p>
Tweet button hidden at start

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Here is also a tweet button, if you see nothing you have my bug demonstrated (don't work with IE or Firefox most of the time)
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="/myUrl" data-text="message" data-hashtags="myhashtag">Tweet</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</p>
</div>
```

***<color=#e12>Jo<color=#Obd>RanGer'***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).